# ¿Cuándo y por qué cambió la conjugación para algunos verbos en español antiguo?

Tags: historia, conjugación

En *[El Cantar de mio Cid](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=VvVJP4bDePAC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Quebranteste%20las%20puertas%20e%20saqueste%20los%20padres%20santos&source=bl&ots=G27bGTeBmG&sig=5cAsxs1_01e_K_5OPiRq5Qv6rGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje-8mAlpvXAhUBSSYKHS32CtkQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=Quebranteste%20las%20puertas%20e%20saqueste%20los%20padres%20santos&f=false)* se puede observar el siguiente texto:

> fuste luego a los infiernos como fue tu voluntad
>
> e quebranteste las puertas, saqueste los santos padres.

La conjugación *quebrant**e**ste* es ahora "quebrant**a**ste" y "saqu**e**ste" es ahora "sac**a**ste". Sin embargo, no en todos los verbos se ve esa predilección por la "e":

> Te encarnaste en Santa María madre,
>
> En Belén apareciste, como fue tu voluntad

¿Hay alguna explicación para esta evolución en la conjugación? ¿Desde cuándo tenemos la conjugación que conocemos actualmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hablamos en estos ejemplos de la segunda persona singular del pretérito simple. La conjugación regular de los verbos de las clases *-er*, *-ir* en esta forma es en *-iste*: *perder* > *perdiste*, *vivir* > *viviste*. En los verbos en *-ar* la forma correspondiente es *-aste*. Estas dos terminaciones provienen regularmente del latín tardío (*-āstī*, *-īstī*).

Lo que ocurre en el fragmento citado del *Mío Cid* es que aparece una forma alternativa terminada en *-este* que existió en competencia con la otra forma durante un cierto tiempo. Dice Paul Lloyd en *[Del latín al español](https://books.google.com.ar/books/about/Del_lat%C3%ADn_al_espa%C3%B1ol_Fonolog%C3%ADa_y_morf.html?id=WXwdAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)*:

> La tendencia a modelar una forma sobre otra dentro del mismo paradigma
>   aparece con especial claridad en el pretérito. Así, comprobamos que la
>   influencia de la forma 1 sobre la 2 (es decir, las formas básicas del
>   diálogo) es muy fuerte. En la conjugación *-ar*, la forma 2 adoptó la
>   /-é/ tónica de la forma 1, y pasó a ser *-este*. En los textos
>   medievales, esta forma aparece frecuentemente en competencia con la
>   originaria *-aste*. En leonés, aparece esta misma vocal en las formas
>   4 y 5 (*-emos* y *-esteis*), y *-emos* aparece todavía en el español
>   popular de Castilla…

Lloyd llama forma 1, 2, etc. a las tradicionales filas de la tabla de conjugación verbal, de manera que "forma 1" es la primera persona del singular, "forma 2" es la segunda del singular (la que nos interesa), "forma 4" es la primera del plural, etc. Lo que dice es que la vocal *-é* de la primera persona del singular influyó por analogía en la terminación de la segunda del singular, cambiando *-aste* por *-este* (*yo saqué* ~ *tú saqueste*) Esta influencia puede haber sido acentuada por el hecho de que se trata de las "formas básicas del diálogo" (o sea, el hablante y el oyente). En la historia de la formación de los verbos castellanos hay muchas de estas influencias analógicas fonéticas.

No me queda claro cuándo desapareció del todo esta forma, pero *saqueste*, por ejemplo, aparece en documentos del CORDE hasta 1476. En el *Libro de buen amor* del Arcipreste de Hita (1330-1346) hay una estrofa repleta de ejemplos (rimados, como para que no quede duda alguna):

> Señor, a los tres niños de muerte los libreste,
>   del forno del gran fuego sin lisïón saqueste:
>   de las ondas del mar a sant Pedro tomeste:
>   Señor, de aquesta coita saca al tu Açipreste.

En la Gramática de 1771, aunque se hacen notar algunas conjugaciones arcaicas ya en desuso, no hay mención de esta conjugación alternativa.

Comment: De hecho, sigue común esa *e* en el leones moderno (es decir, asturiano).  *falar* tiene varias formas con *e*, *fales* y *falen* (son del indicativo), en el pretérito tenemos *falé, falesti/falasti, falemos, falastis/falestis* (cuando hay dos opciones, depende de la zona).  Y en el portugués europeo moderno, no es imposible escuchar una *a* subida que muchas veces tiende casi a una *e*